# How can I prevent R from extrapolating the regression line outside the range of data points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, model, visualization, data-modeling

I am fitting a linear mixed model in R with an interaction term as follows: `model <- lmer(y ~ x * z + (1|h), data = df)`. `y` and `x` are continuous variables and `z` is a categorical variable, and `h` is a random effect.

Data:

```
 n <- 50
df <- tibble::tibble(
  x = rnorm(n),
  z = sample(-1:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  h = sample(1:3, n, replace=TRUE), # random effect
  y = z*(0.5*x) + rnorm(n,0,0.2))
df$z <- as.factor(df$z)
df$h <- as.factor(df$h)
```

Then, I'm using the `plot_predictions()` function from the `marginaleffects` package, then I use `facet_wrap(~ z)` from the `ggplot2` to visualize each regression separately of the different categories as follows:

```
plot_predictions(model, condition = c("x","z"), vcov = T, points= 0.3) + facet_wrap(~ z)
```

As you can notice the first and second plots extrapolate the regression line outside the range of their data according to the limits of data points of the third plot.

So, I try to control this by adding `newdata = df`:

```
plot_predictions(model, new data = df, by = c("x","z"), vcov = T, points= 0.3) + facet_wrap(~ z)
```

however, now I have a new problem; I lose the linear effect and it looks like a disruptive non-continuous line. Interestingly, it only happens when I fit a mixed model with random effects but this is not the case for a simple linear model.

Any idea how I can prevent this from happening, constraining my regression line (+- CIs) to the range of the data points for each panel and keeping the linear model line?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Where does the `plot_prediction` function come from?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that when you use `condition`, the generated grid of prediction values will include every value of `x` in the complete `range(x)`, regardless of whether the values of `x` exist for any given `z`.

A simple way out is to use the original points as `newdata`:

```
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)

# Dummy data
n <- 50
df <- tibble::tibble(
  x = rnorm(n),
  z = sample(-1:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  y = z*(0.5*x) + rnorm(n,0,0.2))
df$z <- as.factor(df$z)

model <- lm(y ~ x * z, data = df)

# Original:
plot_predictions(model, points = 1, condition = c("x","z")) + facet_wrap(~ z)

# Suggested:
plot_predictions(model, points = 1, newdata = df, by = c("x","z")) + facet_wrap(~ z)
```

Comment: Hi @oskar_matzerath, it worked and now the line and confidence intervals are restricted to the limits of the points. It seems that the `condition` function extrapolates the predicted values, however, by using the new version I lost the wiggly effect from the GAM model, and now it looks like a row trend line (without the smooth effect).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, maybe you can modify the code above to replicate what you had in the first place?

Comment: Hi, I already added more details to my question to clarify my problem. Thanks